# Alternative for deprecated session_is_registered

Tags: php

```
session_start();
if (!session_is_registered(user)) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
}
```

What is the proper way to do this since `session_is_registered()` is deprecated?

Comment: It would be helpful if "they" would put a notice in the php manual as to the "recommended" replacement function when something is deprecated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){}`

Comment: would i do that and put an else header("Location: index.php");die(); or die(); isn't needed?

Comment: exit; should always be used after redirecting with header(). die will probably work too.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    // session user does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

isset() will not do what you want all of the time.  It will fail if 'user' is falsy (0, false, null, empty string).  array_key_exists() will match the truth table of session_is_registered, despite what php.net says:

```php
if ( !array_key_exists( 'user', $_SESSION ) ){
  /* 'user' is in the session */
}

//in other words...
if ( array_key_exists( 'user', $_SESSION ) === session_is_registered( 'user' ) ) {
  /* This is always executed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In login.php page, if your username and password is matched then it would register the user by

```
session_register("y"); //where y register the user
header("location:user.php&name=$y");
```

In user.php page

```
session_start();
if(!isset( $_SESSION['y'] )) // if the user is not the same user that logged in then 
{                            // it redirects to the login page
    header("location:login.php");
}
```