# tracking multiple users in CMS with $_SESSION

Tags: php, pdo, multiple-users

Hello I am trying to make multiple users in a CMS I made. I have all their data in a table and was using `mysql_num_rows` check if the records matched and then use `session_register()` to set a session. I have changed this to PDO commands.

I want to be able to track the user when they are using the CMS so that every record changed can have their usrID attached to it. So that at a later date I can see who made updates and eventually use this to show information about the author etc.

So for example when they use forms to update or add a new record a hidden input with have their session id echo'd into it which will be taken from their user record as they log in.

Is the best way to do this? Have a written the syntax in this login code correctly?

```
$con = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE the_username='$the_username' and the_password='$the_password'";

$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();

if($number_of_rows==1){
    $info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $info['the_username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $info['id'];
    header('Location: admin.php');
}else{
echo "Wrong username or password, please refresh and <a href=\"login.php\">try again.</a>";
}
```

Would it perhaps be better to put?

```
if($number_of_rows==1 && $info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){MAKE SESSION}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of PDO functions is quite inconsistent, and it leads to some errors.

First of all, you cannot fetch the same data twice. And, as a matter of fact, you don't need such a double fetch at all.

Also, for some reason you are not using prepared statements which are the only reason for using PDO. So, the proper code would be

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE the_username=? and the_password=?";
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(array($the_username,$the_password)); 
# $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); <- don't need that
$info = $result->fetch();
if($info){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $info['the_username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $info['id'];
    header('Location: admin.php');
}else{
    echo "Wrong username or password, please refresh and <a href=\"login.php\">try again.</a>";
}
```

Comment: Excellent this is fantastic thank you i'll try this. I can see where it was going wrong now.

Comment: After echoing to check it shows its still not setting the $_SESSION. I have no idea why not but I think this is a server issue cos the same happens with my old _mysql_*_ code on all browsers. Everything is sent before all characters etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code and logic works fine. But don't use session_register() they are deprecated in new version of PHP.

Comment: Hello, so I tried loging in like this and its not working, no error and it does get to the else claus. The connection info is all correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Hold on I think I know what it is

Comment: Yea, I still have if(!session_is_registered(name)) type stuff in the header, I guess this has to be changed to PDO aswell

Comment: Yes please change them as using that way is deprecated and not practicing them is not appreciated.

Comment: Yep I will do. The code I have written though is not setting the session becuase when I try to echo the session on the next page nothing.

Comment: Yes session_register might be the issue as I guess you are already on new version of php

Comment: Some alternatives for session_is_registered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286446/alternative-for-deprecated-session-is-registered

Comment: The page is just refreshing I really have no idea what is happening. back to the drawing board

Comment: Now when I input the exact usrname & pswd it still redirects to the login page haha ridiculous. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do You need any help? Because unable to follow completely :)